# windows phone diagnostics logging

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, system.diagnostics

is it possible to get memory and CPU usage in windows phone (sdk 7.1) application?

what would be the best way to retrieve that data from the application for further analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Windows Phone Performance Analysis tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), it allows you to profile CPU usage, memory usage and record garbage collection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to analyze performance as well, take a look at the [Frame Rate counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588380%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (these are enabled by default when you are debugging your app)

You'll want to keep your FPS high, and your screen fill rate low (anything above 3 or so is cause for deep concern, since it means your screen is being redrawn 3x for every frame; not the best thing for performance)

[Jeff Wilcox has a good summary on this too](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/) which is worth reading.